# How to retrieve logged data from the browser console to http server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I  want to use node.js to creat http server that listen to a port 3000 for example. on another port 8000 I am running a javascript for video playing. I am log some data while the vide is playing with console.log but I can not save the logged data to a file directly.I thought of using the http server to do that. But I do not know how to create the post requests from the client to the server.
Can you please help.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Curl is quick: https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58. I know [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is a popular too to stitch together post-requests. Many IDEs has some Rest-client test-utility, as extension or otherwise. (webstorm and  code included).  You can also right-click requests in chrome network tab and copy as curl, very handy. Or google "online rest api test" and you'll find a bunch easy to use tools.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I used the http server and that solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the default `console.log` function with a custom function that make a post request every time you log something.

```
let originalConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function (...args) {
  postLog(args);  // Send logs to the server
  originalConsoleLog.apply(console, args);  // Call the original console.log function
}
```

where the `postLog` function will send the data to the nodejs and can be something like

```
function postLog(args) {
  var newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

  newXHR.addEventListener( 'load', reqListener );
  newXHR.open( 'POST', '/saveLog' );
  var jsonData = { logs: args };
  var formattedJsonData = JSON.stringify( jsonData );

  newXHR.send( formattedJsonData );
}
```

postLog function based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sgnl/bd760187214681cdb6dd)

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I am quite beginner with nodejs, should I add the postLog function to the server or the javascript?
and `args` in this case are the arguments I want to log.. ?

Comment: the `postLog` function works in the browser and makes a `POST` request to nodejs. Yes `args` are the arguments you pass to `console.log`